# Pascal- не получается сделать вывод массива из функции

Tags: pascal

Как правильно записать?...с функцией 
Код:

```
const
    n=10;
    m=15;
type 
    mas=array [1..n,1..m] of integer;
        var
i:integer;
function min (var a:mas;n,m:integer):integer;
var
i,j:integer;    
    begin
    randomize;
    for i:=1 to n do
        for j:=1 to m do
        a[i,j]:=random(50)-10;
min:=a;
    end;
        var
        a:mas;
i,j:integer;
begin
writeln('massiv');

min(a);
for i:=1 to n do begin
    for j:=1 to m do begin
    write(a[i,j]);
    end;
    writeln;
    end;
end.
```

Comment: Это игра такая — задать и ответить самому?

Comment: ответ вроде отличается только в строке с random

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const
    n=10;
    m=15;
type 
    mas=array [1..n,1..m] of integer;
        var
        a:mas;
i:integer;
function min (var aa:mas):mas;
var
i,j:integer;    
    begin
    randomize;
    for i:=1 to n do
        for j:=1 to m do
        aa[i,j]:=random(5)-10;
min:=aa;
    end;
        var
j:integer;
begin
writeln('massiv');
min(a);
for i:=1 to n do begin
    for j:=1 to m do begin
    write(a[i,j]:2);
    end;
    writeln;
    end;
end.
```